# Restricting function template parameter to certain types

Tags: c++, templates

I have a function with two template parameters

```
template<class X, class Y>
bool fun(X x, Y y) { ... }
```

I need to restrict second parameter to the following two cases: `int y` or `vector<int> const& y`. If I try to `static_assert`:

```
static_assert( std::is_same<int, Y>::value ||
               std::is_same<std::vector<int> const&, Y>::value,
               "unsupported Y class" );
```

Then the following does not compile

```
X x;
std::vector<int> y;
fun(x, y);
```

because Y is deduced to be `vector<int>` instead of `vector<int> const&`.

Is there a way to restrict Y the way I want?

PS: Of course, I can call `fun<X, vector<int> const&>( x, y )` but I want automatic type deduction to work. Or I can copy and paste and have two functions respectively, but it is a long function with same body, which I keep changing, so I don't like synchronizing two copies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to be able to pass in anything that's implicitly convertible to `int` or `const std::vector<int>&`, but you want the actual parameter type to be `int` or `const std::vector<int>&`, and you don't want to repeat the implementation. So, do this:

```
template <class X, class Y>
bool actual_fun(X x, Y y) {
    // actual implementation
}

template <class X>
bool fun(X x, int y) {
    return actual_fun<X, int>(x, y);
}

template <class X>
bool fun(X x, const std::vector<int>& y) {
    return actual_fun<X, const std::vector<int>&>(x, y);
}
```

(You may want to wrap `actual_fun` in a `namespace detail` or something of that sort.)

Answer (score 0):

`Y` will never be deduced as `const vector<int>&`. That will only happen if that type is explicitly provided by the user.

```
X x;
std::vector<int> y;
fun(x, y); // Y deduced as std::vector<int>
fun<X, const std::vector<int>&>(x, y); // Y deduced as const std::vector<int>&
```

So if you don't expect types to be used explicitly, you can just `static_assert` against the expected types:

```
static_assert( std::is_same<int, Y>::value ||
               std::is_same<std::vector<int>, Y>::value,
               "unsupported Y class" );
```

However, if you want to handle even the case where the caller provides the types explicitly, then you want to use [`std::decay`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay):

```
using dY = typename std::decay<Y>::type;
```

That will drop the `const` and `&` qualifiers. And then, you can do your static assert with neither:

```
static_assert( std::is_same<int, dY>::value ||
               std::is_same<std::vector<int>, dY>::value,
               "unsupported Y class" );
```